# string parse and replace in for loop

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing

I have a string that looks like this,

```
"1AL||9CA||34CO||196WY||..."
```

I want to use a for loop or while loop, in which if I have an integer, it should parse this string and delete the value matching that integer.

For example,

```
string = "1AL||9CA||34CO||196WY||..."
integer = 34

for 
...
loop

new string = "1AL||9CA||196WY||..."
```

As you can see the integer matched the integer 34 and deleted from one delimiter "||" to the next one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

- First split the string and then store the array.
- Now loop through the array and using indexof function check for the integer value in the array element.
- Remove that element from the array.
- Finally use the `Join` function to join the elements which is the result you want.